# Sorting Multiple arrays in Desc order  in PHP

Tags: php

I need to sort following array in desc order by `ref_no`. Eg: At location `[0]` there should be property with id `16` (since it's `ref_no` is greater) and at `[1]` property with id `10`.

*Please note: The size of main array is dynamic and that of Property array remains same.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Property] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [member_id] => 2
                [ref_no] => 333
             }
     )


  [1] => Array
    (
        [Property] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16
                [member_id] => 4
                [ref_no] => 509
             }
     )

 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
  usort($input, function ($a, $b) {return ($a['ref_no']>$b['ref_no']);});
```